# Rails: how to create new nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just tried to create new nested items(candidates) with `Cocoon` gem. Currently views shows not create form but update form, how can I change form.

I want to try to show just create form.

```
<%= form_with(model: @title) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :candidates do |candidate| %>
    <div class="candidate-item">
        <%= candidate.hidden_field :title_id, value: @title.id %>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Candidate</label>
            <%= candidate.text_field :name%>
        </div>
        <div class="field file-field">
            <label>Image</label>
            <%= candidate.file_field :image, :type => "file" %> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

I tried it like this:
`form_with(model: @title, url: new_candidates_path` but an undefined error occurs. Candidates nested for titles. Please let me know any ideas which shows not update form, create form.

Answer (score 1):

To allow adding and removing items use `link_to_add_association` and `link_to_remove_association` metthods as example below

```
<%= form_with(model: @title) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :candidates do |candidate| %>
    <div class="candidate-item">
      <%= candidate.hidden_field :title_id, value: @title.id %>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Candidate</label>
        <%= candidate.text_field :name%>
      </div>
      <div class="field file-field">
        <label>Image</label>
        <%= candidate.file_field :image, :type => "file" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field file-field">
        <%= link_to_remove_association 'remove candidates', candidate %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field file-field">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'add candidates', f, :candidates %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks @mehedi I can make it :)

Comment: @ShunYamada If my answer solves your problem, will you please accept it as a solution. Thanks